# Issues with Batch Taskkill of Parent MSAccess Process

Tags: vba, batch-file, ms-access, taskkill

**Process Tree:**

I have an MS Access version control macro that checks users current file version on open, and if not up-to-date, the macro launches a batch file that 1) *should* delete their current file, and then 2) copies the up-to-date front-end version from the network and pastes it on their local system.

**My issue:**

Everything works EXCEPT for the deletion of the users original file.  Since this file is the parent process of the batch file I haven't found a way to Kill the task so it can be deleted.

**Current Code:**

```
TASKKILL /F /fi /IM MSACCESS.EXE /T

del "%originalFile%"
```

**I thought maybe I was having issues because the batch was a child of the Access process, so I've also tried with no luck:

```
TASKKILL /F /fi /IM MSACCESS.EXE
```

I always get the error:

> ERROR: Invalid syntax. Value expected for '/fi'.

Its been a long day, so I assume I'm missing something simple and would love an extra set of eyes.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Read the help for the TASKKILL command.  You are not using the `/FI` option correctly. You are confusing it with the syntax for the TASKLIST command. You do not need /FI

Comment: @Squashman - thanks for the extra set of eyes. Removing /fi worked and the process successfully killed. Unfortunately I'm still getting part of my original issue, which is "the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process". -- Hopefully by using your response coupled with the answer from Andre451 of sleeping the batch, I will be able to get this completed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar setup, but without TASKKILL.

Directly after launching my update batch, I do `Application.Quit`

```
' If need to update
Shell UPDATE_BATCH, vbNormalFocus
Application.Quit
```

And in the update batch, I wait for 3 seconds so that Access has enough time to exit (and release the lock on the frontend).

```
sleep.exe 3
REM ... copy new frontend ...
sleep.exe 1
REM ... start MSACCESS command line ...
```

How to "sleep"? See here: [SLEEP.exe (2003 Resource Kit)](http://ss64.com/nt/sleep.html) for different variants.

Comment: Ahh nice!  I already tired that as well, but without the sleep.  I'll give this a try and mark as correct if it works.

Comment: I ended up using TIMEOUT rather than sleep.exe, but works perfect.  Thanks!