# Clarification on splitting an Access Database

Tags: database, forms, vba, ms-access, database-design

I've read multiple articles and watched videos but this is a big change to the structure so I want to confirm the idea that I have.

Splitting will separate the tables and forms/queries into separate files. I get that much. But two questions.

1) Should I backup my database beforehand?

2) Can I edit the forms in design/layout view while they're being used by, say, a data entry team?

The issue I'm running into now is that I created a simplistic front end for another team to use but I now need to buff it up while they use it. I heard this was the most efficient way to do so.

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes, of course.

2) Every user should have their own local copy of the frontend.

You develop the new frontend version on your local computer, then when it's ready you put it on a network drive, and everyone gets their new local frontend from there.

Here are some ideas how to automate this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33782644/3820271

You should never make design changes on a database that other users are currently using. (shudder)

**Edit** re. comment:

All forms are in the frontend, so yes. You work on your development frontend, connected to a development backend (a copy of the production backend).

The other users can meanwhile work with their local frontends on the production backend.

When you are ready for release, make the necessary changes in the production backend (if there are changes in table structures). Make a copy of your dev frontend and link the tables from prod backend. This is the new prod frontend, which is distributed to all users.

Comment: So if I need to edit a form, or better yet develop a brand new form that's more robust, do I accomplish that on the front end? At the same time they're using it for data entry? Another question -- we're having issues with certain users accessing the database. Most of the time they can access, others it talks about a locked state. We're also seeing an issue where some users can't open the data entry form and it's giving them an error with the file path to the backend. Works for other users though. Why could that be? Thank you!

Comment: See edit. For the other question, please post as new question with more details (setup, exact error messages etc.)

Comment: It is not necessary for every user to have their own front end. They can still share a single network based front end while you can do development on a separate copy of the front end. There are however some advantages, depending on your design and how advanced the front end is, to each user having their own front end.