# Is there any way to read non-text clipboard data from Access VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, clipboard

I have a database where I've implemented drag-and-drop for file and emails/attachments, but my users have 1280p screens so I'm thinking it might be easier for them to copy & paste instead (I would probably just use a "Use Data From Clipboard" button). Problem is, all the VBA code I see for getting data from the clipboard is geared towards using Excel userforms, and the MS Forms library I need for the DataObject object and GetFromClipboard method isn't even available without creating a userform.

I guess it would be possible to kludge something together to open a hidden Excel workbook with a userform to act as some kind of data broker, but I really don't want to add that overhead.

Answer (score 1):

This question has some misconceptions.

1. You can reference Microsoft Forms in Access just fine. Just open the reference browser, browse to System32, add FM20.dll
2. You can use `GetFromClipboard` without creating a userform just fine. Just add the reference first, then:

   ```
    Dim d As New DataObject
    d.GetFromClipboard
   ```

There are also examples about how to use the clipboard from WinAPI in Access, e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/windows-api/retrieve-information-from-the-clipboard for text, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/53161232/7296893 for spreadhseet data.

Comment: Not a misconception. Fm20.dll  literally did not exist anywhere in my entire Windows folder. I gave in and created a spreadsheet with a userform so I could get the dll, but it's still not exactly an ideal solution given that there will be other users. It does seem to work, though. I'll take a look at the API code too. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't have fm20.dll, it should be installed with Office. It also shouldn't be possible for Excel to place a file in System32 without admin privileges, so it appearing after creating a userform in Excel sounds odd. No need to use Excel to create userforms, you can just do so in Access, see https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/how-to-create-a-new-userform-in-access-vba.2424570/post-7871509 among others.

Comment: Thanks - I can't explain it either, but that actually appears to be the standard behavior. It turned out to be moot as the DataObject didn't really meet my needs, so I ended up going the API route anyway.